# ncurses not doing anything even after initialized

Tags: c++, ncurses

So I was following a tutorial of ncurses in linux, but it doesnt do anything. Here's my code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main()
{
    initscr();
    printw("Tset");
    refresh();
    endwin();
}
```

When i compile it using `g++ main.cpp -lncurses` it works but it doesnt even output a single thing. Not even clearing the screen. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `endwin()` is closing your ncurses window after printing **"Tset"**. It is quick and you don't see it. You could make the program wait for some key to be pressed before closing the window to see the output.  Use `getch()` before ending the window.

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>
int main()
{
    initscr();
    printw("Tset");
    refresh();
    getch();    //add this line to wait for keypress
    endwin();
}
```